# How RethinkDB joins are implemented?

Tags: rethinkdb, nosql

I've been poking RethinkDB lately, and was very scared to see joins documentation section. From what i know, RethinkDB stores data in shards, which may be distributed (and that's afaik practically a huge **NO** for joins). So how does RethinkDB perform join queries? Does it basically download all data on one node (that would render existing indexes useless, wouldn't it?), or does it use more complicated algorithm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In RethinkDB 2.2 and before, an `eqJoin` performs an indexes `getAll` operation on the right-hand table for each document in the left-hand input.
This operation is initiated on each of the shards that are hosting the left-hand input of the `eqJoin` command.
As you point out, performing the `getAll` might require going over the network to reach a shard of the right-hand table on a different server. However indexes are still being used.

(you can find the implementation of `eqJoin` here: https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/blob/v2.2.x/src/rdb_protocol/terms/rewrites.cc#L121 It's just a rewrite to other operations)

Starting with the upcoming RethinkDB 2.3, `eqJoin` uses batched `getAll` operations. This means that it reads a bunch of results (e.g. up to 1 MB) from the left-hand input, and then issues a single `getAll` to the shards of the right-hand table. Once it gets the data back from those shards, it combines it with the data it had previously read from the left input and passes it on to the user. Then it repeats this until all data from the left input has been processed.
This approach requires significantly fewer network roundtrips between the servers, and is usually significantly faster. You can find some more details about the new implementation at https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/5115 .

Finally, the other available join operations (`innerJoin` and `outerJoin`) are not indexed and shouldn't be used for data sets of any significant size as the documentation also points out.